# Error: Reading rich text fields is not supported pdf-lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on nextjs project where I have to write some text in fields in pdf placed on the server. Whenever I try to right and save the document it gives the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reading rich text fields is not supported: Attempted to 
read rich text field: Summary of care provided
```

I am using [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) library to achieve this thing but facing this error:
[image: See Error Here]

The Code I am using to get this done:

```js
import { degrees, PDFDocument, rgb, StandardFonts } from "pdf-lib";
export default async function () {
  // Fetch an existing PDF document
  let response = await fetch(
    "https://url/application.pdf"
  );
  let bytes = await response.arrayBuffer();

  // Load a PDFDocument from the existing PDF bytes
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(bytes);

  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

  const textField = form.getTextField("City");

  textField.setText("One Punch Man");
  textField.enableReadOnly();
  // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
  const urlChan = window.URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: "application/pdf" })
  );
  window.open(urlChan);
}
```

Here we have this field on page no 8 of the pdf:
[image: See here]

I tried multiple methods given by [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) but nothing worked.